# Issue with Jmeter Beanshellcode for file writing

Tags: jmeter, beanshell, file-writing

I am currently working on a jmeter JDBC scripts which involves executing huge queries on the DB to setup data for test.

Its a bit of a complex script where I need to validate and extract specific filed from the result set and then write it all in the file and use in the next thread group

I written a Beanshell code as below to validate a particulat condition

```
FileWriter fWriter = new FileWriter ("C:/UserPath/Number.csv", true);
BufferedWriter buff = new BufferedWriter(fWriter);
if (${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == true)
{
buff.write(vars.get("p_PI_ID") +  ","  +  vars.get("p_AC_Number"));
buff.write(System.getProperty("line.separator"));
log.info(vars.get("Update_Assertion"));
}
buff.close();
```

The condition is I want the data to be written to the file when the JMeterThread.last_sample_ok= true

I have tried various combination to write this up but this code write to the file no matter what the condition is. So far I have tried the below conditions

if (${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == true)

if (${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} != false)

if (!${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == false)

I did also try to use some other logics to no success, the thing is this code works fine with other validation I am doing, not sure what is wrong here

I have also tried to place the beanshell post processor outside the JDBC sample which should then capture the state of the sampler execution as True or false.

Thanks for reading though.

Comment: `${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} ` checks the status of the last sampler. When you want to check the status of the Sampler attached to post-processors such as a Bean Shell you may use `prev.isSuccessful()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try with

```
if (prev.isSuccessful()){

}
```

BTW it is recommended to switch to JSR223 Elements from [Beanshell](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#BeanShell_PostProcessor).
[image]

Comment: Thanks @Janesh Kodikara, I think the issue was with beanshell, not sure what, I tried the above condition using JSR223 post processer and it worked

Answer (score 1):

Don't inline [JMeter Functions or Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) into scripts, either use Parameters section or go for code-based equivalents instead. So change this line:

```
if (${JMeterThread.last_sample_ok} == true)
```

to this one:

```
if (vars.get("JMeterThread.last_sample_ok").equals("true"))
```

where `vars` stands for [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more information on this and other JMeter API shorthands available for the JSR223 Test Elements.

Another option is put this variable into "Parameters" section and go for `if (Parameters.equals("true"))` expression:

[image]

And last but not the least [since JMeter 3.1 you're supposed to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) so it might worth considering migrating.